# using split in azure stream analytics

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I have strings in the format "1234.567.111". I wish to break it into three int.

I do not see a split function in azure stream analytics. Is it possible to do this any other way.

Thanks

Update:

I have added a request for split function [here..](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/270577-azure-stream-analytics/suggestions/8991559-add-the-split-function-along-with-other-scalar-fun), would appreciate if you guys voted for the same..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish Stream Analytics had a split function. You may have to use CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING for now:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn835064.aspx

It's a bit of a pain, but the following should work:

```
SELECT mystring
,SUBSTRING(
  mystring
  ,0
  ,CHARINDEX('.',mystring)
 ) as segment1
,SUBSTRING(
  mystring
  ,CHARINDEX('.',mystring)+1
  ,CHARINDEX('.',mystring,CHARINDEX('.',mystring)+1) - CHARINDEX('.',mystring) - 1
 ) as segment2
,SUBSTRING(
  mystring
  ,CHARINDEX('.',mystring,CHARINDEX('.',mystring)+1)+1
  ,999
 ) as segment3
from myinput
```

I would request a split function here (and post the link so we can vote):
http://feedback.azure.com/forums/270577-azure-stream-analytics

Comment: Could you please give an example and show how to use the said functions in my case..

Comment: Edited my answer to provide an example

Comment: WOW.. Thanks.. would really appreciate if you could also show what would happen if the string had three '.' Please update your answer by adding below rather than removing the current one..

Comment: The third segment would look like 333.444

Comment: What I meant was what would happen if my string was"1234.567.111.5678"

Comment: Third segment would return 111.5678. If you need to handle 4 segments you need to change the code to handle that.

Comment: Yes, would appreciate if you could add the code in case of four segments

Comment: I will leave that up to you to work it out from the example I gave for 3 segments per your question on 3 segments

Comment: I have also added a request for the split function as per your advice.. do vote

Comment: Arnab, you are right. I've fixed the answer now. Good catch.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone ends up here 7 years later like me  Still no split function in 2022, but easy enough to create a simple JS UDF albeit probably with a small execution resource/time penalty

```
function main(splitstr, splitchar, index) {
    var res = null;

    try {
        res = splitstr.split(splitchar)[index];
    }catch(error){
        throw splitstr;
    }

    return res;
}
```