# I am receiving the downstream message which contains more than one processed data

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

In event hub a receiving more than 1 processed message ,the message is not coming as individual events.the message contains more than 1 item.

if you see the message it has more than one item of device info,I should receive one item per event.

```
    //Processing the message
    With ProcessedPayload As 
    (SELECT
    udf.Device(
    Event.meta.DeviceId,
    Event.meta,
    Event.Data_in,
    Event.channels,
    pcmsqlazure.ConfigIOPayload) As device

    FROM
        localINputsignal As Event
    join
        pcmsqlazure
    ON
     Event.meta.DeviceId=pcmsqlazure.SerialNumber) 
//output data to event bus
    select device.deviceId,device.productFilter,device.data into Custom from ProcessedPayload
```

---

Edit:

The data coming like below as a single string

```
{"Ts":"2019-08-28T04:08:23.3884855Z","DeviceId":"DJT3COE4","count":1} 
{"Ts":"2019-08-28T04:08:23.0584507Z","DeviceId":"DJT3COE4","count":1} 
{"Ts":"2019-08-28T04:08:21.8236859Z","DeviceId":"DJT3COE4","count":1} 
{"Ts":"2019-08-28T04:08:21.8236859Z","DeviceId":"DJT3COE4","count":1}
```

but for me the result should come as single event like below

```
{"Ts":"2019-08-28T04:08:21.8236859Z","DeviceId":"DJT3COE4","count":1}
```

Q: the processed downstream message which is the message pusblished to Eventhub,and this message should be received one by one,is anything i need to do in the query?

Comment: You mean the messages come as an array?

Comment: its coming like below      as a single string     {"Ts":"2019-08-28T04:08:23.3884855Z","DeviceId":"DJT3COE4","count":1}
{"Ts":"2019-08-28T04:08:23.0584507Z","DeviceId":"DJT3COE4","count":1}
{"Ts":"2019-08-28T04:08:21.8236859Z","DeviceId":"DJT3COE4","count":1}
{"Ts":"2019-08-28T04:08:21.8236859Z","DeviceId":"DJT3COE4","count":1} but for me the result should come as single event like below {"Ts":"2019-08-28T04:08:21.8236859Z","DeviceId":"DJT3COE4","count":1}

Comment: the processed downstream message which is the message pusblished to Eventhub,and this message should be received one by one,is anything i need to do in the query?

Answer (score 0):

> In event hub a receiving more than 1 processed message ,the message is
>   not coming as individual events.the message contains more than 1 item.

I'm afraid that you need to parse such coming string into JsonArray with User Defined Function in ASA.

Since split function is not supported by ASA yet so far,you could refer to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31555293/using-split-in-azure-stream-analytics) to use CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING [functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/charindex-azure-stream-analytics).